# Unable to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

When I try to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, I get the following message :

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable
>
> Click ok to try again or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'sqlncli_x64.msi' in the below box

I'm unable to find a way to solve this problem. Can you help me ?

Comment: Maybe it didn't download properly and is corrupted. Does it do this immediately or does it do it in the middle? Do you actually have the file 'sqlncli_x64.msi'? What is the name of the file you downloaded to install? sqlncli is actually just the client piece. What OS? Are you an admin?

Comment: You right, the installer was corrupt. Installed that I had was downloaded by a setup file (created from visual studio). The file had a size of 85 Mo. I downloaded the sql installer from microsoft.com, this time the installer (with the same name) had a size of 135Mo. And this time the installation works fine. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for returning with your findings. It helps when people can confirm these things.

Answer (score 0):

For me this got fixed by -

1. Going to registry editor (windows+R > regedit)
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Classes > Installer > Products
3. Goto each key listed under Products and delete all keys related to SQL Server (or the keys you think are specific to your error). This can be done by clicking on the key folder and reading the ProductName details in right pane (delete only the keys that contain keywords like SQL Server).
4. Once step 3 is complete, restart your machine and try again.